# Reactions in Djs12

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have a problem with the newest Discord.js (12). I just updated my bot a few days ago, and everything is fine, but one command. I have a `!vote` command, which reacts to a message. For example, if I type **!vote 3**, it reacts with 1, 2, 3. My bot sends a feedback to the channel (Vote created) but it doesn't reacts with any number.

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'vote',
    description: 'Szavazás létrehozása',
    guildOnly: true,
    dmOnly: false,
    adminOnly: false,
    execute(message, args) {
        console.log(`Vote - Start with argument ${args[0]}`)
        const channel = message.channel;
        if (!args[0]) {
            message.channel.send("Adj meg egy paramétert!");
        } else {
            console.log("Vote - Else")
        const parameter = parseInt(args[0], 10);
        if (parameter > 10 || parameter < 0) {
            message.channel.send("Adj meg egy 0 és 10 közötti számot!");
            return;
        }
        console.log("Vote - Before Delete")
        message.delete({ timeout: 1 })
        .then(() => channel.fetchMessages({ limit: 1 }).then(messages => {
            console.log("Vote - Before let lastMessage")
            let lastMessage = messages.first();
            if (lastMessage.member != message.member && !message.member.roles.cache.some(r=>r.name==="botadmin")) {
                message.channel.send("Nem tőled származik az előző üzenet.");
                return;
            }
          
                console.log("Vote - Before Switch")
                switch (args[0]) {
                    case "0":
                        lastMessage.react("✅")
                        .then(() => lastMessage.react("❎"));
                        break;
                    case "10":
                        lastMessage.react('1️⃣')
                        .then (() => lastMessage.react('2️⃣'))
                        .then (() => lastMessage.react('3️⃣'))
                        .then (() => lastMessage.react('4️⃣'))
                        .then (() => lastMessage.react('5️⃣'))
                        .then (() => lastMessage.react('6️⃣'))
                        .then (() => lastMessage.react('7️⃣'))
                        .then (() => lastMessage.react('8️⃣'))
                        .then (() => lastMessage.react('9️⃣'))
                        .then (() => lastMessage.react(''))
                        break;
                    case "9":
                        lastMessage.react('1️⃣')
                        .then (() => lastMessage.react('2️⃣'))
                        .then (() => lastMessage.react('3️⃣'))
                        .then (() => lastMessage.react('4️⃣'))
                        .then (() => lastMessage.react('5️⃣'))
                        .then (() => lastMessage.react('6️⃣'))
                        .then (() => lastMessage.react('7️⃣'))
                        .then (() => lastMessage.react('8️⃣'))
                        .then (() => lastMessage.react('9️⃣'))
                        break;
                    case "8":
                        lastMessage.react('1️⃣')
                        .then (() => lastMessage.react('2️⃣'))
                        .then (() => lastMessage.react('3️⃣'))
                        .then (() => lastMessage.react('4️⃣'))
                        .then (() => lastMessage.react('5️⃣'))
                        .then (() => lastMessage.react('6️⃣'))
                        .then (() => lastMessage.react('7️⃣'))
                        .then (() => lastMessage.react('8️⃣'))
                        break;
                    case "7":
                        lastMessage.react('1️⃣')
                        .then (() => lastMessage.react('2️⃣'))
                        .then (() => lastMessage.react('3️⃣'))
                        .then (() => lastMessage.react('4️⃣'))
                        .then (() => lastMessage.react('5️⃣'))
                        .then (() => lastMessage.react('6️⃣'))
                        .then (() => lastMessage.react('7️⃣'))
                        break;
                    case "6":
                        lastMessage.react('1️⃣')
                        .then (() => lastMessage.react('2️⃣'))
                        .then (() => lastMessage.react('3️⃣'))
                        .then (() => lastMessage.react('4️⃣'))
                        .then (() => lastMessage.react('5️⃣'))
                        .then (() => lastMessage.react('6️⃣'))
                        break;
                    case "5":
                        lastMessage.react('1️⃣')
                        .then (() => lastMessage.react('2️⃣'))
                        .then (() => lastMessage.react('3️⃣'))
                        .then (() => lastMessage.react('4️⃣'))
                        .then (() => lastMessage.react('5️⃣'))
                        break;
                    case "4":
                        lastMessage.react('1️⃣')
                        .then (() => lastMessage.react('2️⃣'))
                        .then (() => lastMessage.react('3️⃣'))
                        .then (() => lastMessage.react('4️⃣'))
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        lastMessage.react('1️⃣')
                        .then (() => lastMessage.react('2️⃣'))
                        .then (() => lastMessage.react('3️⃣'))
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        lastMessage.react('1️⃣')
                        .then (() => lastMessage.react('2️⃣'))
                        break;
                    case "1":
                        lastMessage.react('1️⃣')
                        break;
                }
                
          }))
          const Discord = require('discord.js');
          const confirm = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setColor("GREEN")
          .setDescription("Szavazás létrehozva. Reagálj a megfelelő emojival a szavazáshoz!");
          message.channel.send(confirm);
    } ; }
}
```

As you can see, I'm, logging to console every single steps and it logs this only:

```
Vote - Start with argument 3
Vote - Else
Vote - Before Delete
```

It is really strange, because the *message.channel.send(confirm)* is after reactions.

How can I fix this?